# Why did CSB translate H2850 in 1 Kings 11:1 as Hittite while the one in 1 Kings 15:5 as Hethite?

Tags: 1-kings

Christian Standard Bible 1 Kings 11:1

> King Solomon loved many foreign women in addition to Pharaoh’s daughter: Moabite, Ammonite, Edomite, Sidonian, and **Hittite** [H2850] women

1 Kings 15:5

> For David did what was right in the LORD’s sight, and he did not turn aside from anything he had commanded him all the days of his life, except in the matter of Uriah the **Hethite** [H2850].

This seems to be an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

There is some basis for the CSB transliteration.

There are two distinct groups of people referenced in the OT with names starting with חת, *Heth*.

The first is a Canaanite ethnic subgroup that was already indigenous to the promised land at the time of Abraham. It is from Ephron the Heth-ite that Abraham purchases the family burial plot in Hebron. These people are reputed to be the sons of Heth son of Canaan son of Noah. The reference in 1 Kings 15:5 is to a person, Uriah, who was a member of or descendant of this same ethnic group, so Uriah *hahithi* in Hebrew is a **Hethite** in the CSB Englilsh tranliteration.

The second group of people are referred to as חתיים, *Hitites*, in the OT are the people who established the Hittite empire in northern Syria and Turkye in about BCE 1430, a long time after Abraham. These people are a national or political group, not necessarily an ethnic group.

In 1 Kings 11:1 the word in question in Hebrew is חִתִּיֹּת, *hittiot*, a plural feminine noun form. From the context of the word in the verse we see that this is a reference to women, from the **Hittite** empire with whom king Solomon contracted political marriages.

For more detail see [Hittites and Hethites: A Proposed Solution to an Etymological Conundrum](https://biblearchaeology.org/research/divided-kingdom/2796-hittites-and-hethites-a-proposed-solution-to-an-etymological-conundrum).